# Clojure IllegalStateException Can't dynamically bind non-dynamic var:

Tags: clojure, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to install Clojuratica and am getting this error

```
IllegalStateException Can't dynamically bind non-dynamic var: clojuratica.runtime.dynamic-vars/*kernel*  clojure.lang.Var.pushThreadBindings (Var.java:353)
```

When executing this command:

```
(def math-evaluate ^:dynamic (math-evaluator kernel-link))
```

from the instructions on this page:

http://clojuratica.weebly.com/tutorial.html

The error looks like it's something to do with this page:

https://github.com/gasc/Clojuratica/blob/master/src/clj/clojuratica.clj

Anyone know how this could be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of Clojuratica seems to require an a version of clojure < 1.3.0 because it does not mark it's dynamic variables as such (and at that time it was not required).

It looks like the latest version on the [projects github page](https://github.com/gasc/Clojuratica/tree/master) fixes this.